# Refresh other input fields when one of the fields is updated. Using Angularjs (Plunker attached)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Here is the plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ll09uMtJEC0HqyGBRPjH?p=preview

As seen in the plunker, i have a date, user and car as input fields. I am able to select a date, user and car.

However if i now try to change the date, i want the user and car should be back to blank (no value should be shown)

how can i achieve this.

```
<html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use ng-change directive, when the date is changed

in the input tag for date in your view :

```
ng-change="clearInputFields()"
```

in your controller :

```
$scope.clearInputFields = function() { 
  $scope.params.car = "";
  $scope.params.user = {}; // or "" if it was a string
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Haha.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ng-change` in the datepicker. with adding for example `ng-change="resetvalue()"`

`ng-change` is to call function or do something when the value is changing

and in the function resetvalue

```
$scope.resetvalue = function(){
  $scope.params.user = '';
  $scope.params.car = '';
}
```